# TcpClient 505 HTTP Version Not Supported

Tags: c#, tcpclient

```
var client = new TcpClient("www.example.com", 80);
var message = @"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
var stream = client.GetStream();
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
data = new byte[256];
var bytes = await stream.ReadAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
var responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
```

First line of response: HTTP/1.0 505 HTTP Version Not Supported

Note:  Using HttpClient/HttpWebRequest is not an option for my use case.   It's a long story beyond the scope of this specific question.

Edit:  I also tried

```
var message = @"GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
```

Comment: Perhaps the server only supports HTTP/2.0? Probably not related, but I would recommend using `\n` instead of `\r\n`.

Comment: @Llama Well, I tried just to be sure.  Same error.  Also tried using \n instead of \r\n, same result.

Comment: @Llama: That would be invalid. RFC2616 dictates the use of CRLF, not LF.

Comment: @Jon Really? Oh. Noted.

Comment: Did you try `GET/ HTTP/1.0`?  Because 1.1 seems to be "not supported"...

Comment: @Luuk Yes, that was the first thing I did before posting this.  I'll edit my post to mention that.

Comment: Then you might need something like Fiddler, or Wireshark, to see how successful communication to example.com is behaving.  (see i.e.: [How to capture HTTP traffic using Wireshark, Fiddler, or tcpdump](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/how-to-capture-http-traffic-using-wireshark-or-fiddler-779164332.html) )

Comment: +1 for using Fiddler or Wireshark to look at a successful communication. Perhaps a header the server expects to always be there is missing?

Comment: It's extremely strange that you can use such a recent .NET version (hint: `await`) but you cannot use an HttpClient. Sounds like an XY problem honestly. You'll probably need to check another application that can actually connect to example.com and look at how the request is being sent, as @Luuk mentioned

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Well, if you would like an explanation, here goes:

A server that I am trying to interact with is fingerprinting my use of HttpClient, probably through certain traits of the Client Hello message during the TLS handshake that HttpClient is sending.  This server is also able to detect when I have Fiddler running, which is likely due to the certificate.  I am trying to communicate with this server at a lower level of abstraction, to give me more control over the communication.

Comment: @Luuk I just sent the request using Postman, with no headers, and the request was successful.  Shows the header as the same as what I am sending with TCP Client when I analyze the request in Fiddler.

Comment: But Postman sends a lot more headers by default as well, could it not be that those extra headers are used by the server and, when missing, it just gives you a confusing 505?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I disabled all of the default headers (even the User-Agent).  I can see the raw request and successful response in Fiddler (and in Postman, for the response).

Comment: I don't think you can actually disable User-Agent in Postman.

Comment: @Llama

You can.  Image:  https://ibb.co/LnHsPZt

That request was sent from Postman.

Comment: Ah, it seems you can with the newer version. I (finally) updated from the old Chrome-based version and you can now. Anyway, if you can't use Fiddler or Wireshark to figure out what's wrong with your request, I suggest talking to the people running the server.

Comment: @Llama While I appreciate the response, I doubt I will get help from the server admins.  Anyways, the same request works when sent from Postman, but not with TcpClient.  This seems like a strange edge case issue with TcpClient, not the server itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare what you are sending:
[image]

Against what you want to send:
[image]

Which boils down to incorrectly assigning `message` a string literal. You need a regular string instead:

```
var message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
```

As otherwise, what you send is actually wrong: `GET / HTTP/1.1\\r\\nHost:  example.com\\r\\nConnection:  close\\r\\n\\r\\n`